# Can zsh or bash expand history expressions referring to directories?

Tags: bash, zsh, tab-completion, bash-completion, zsh-completion

For example, let's suppose I just copied something:

```
mv foo_file.txt ~/to/some/long/path/that/i/do/not/want/to/retype
```

and I'd like to use history substitution like so:

```
mv bar_file.txt !!:2
```

I'm surprised that zsh is not expanding the `!!:2` for me when I hit [tab].  In a more complex reference to a historical argument I might really want the expansion before I hit return, just so I know with certainty that I referred to the correct argument.  Is there any way to make it do that?  (I would expect that to be the default behavior.  Is it the default behavior, that I have somehow inadvertently disabled or broken?)

If zsh can't do it, can bash?

**UPDATE**: zsh will expand the history expression if it refers to a file, but not a directory:

```
mv foo_file.txt foo_bar_file.txt
mv bar_file.txt !!:2[TAB]
```

It will expand it if it is just an arbitrary string:

```
echo one two three four
echo !!:1[TAB]
```

But not if you're trying to move something to a directory.  It looks more and more like this must be a bug.

Comment: it does tab-complete for me, zsh 4.2.7.

Comment: @chad: I'm using zsh 4.3.10, and it doesn't work for me.  Are you moving to a directory?  It works for me if I'm simply renaming a file, but not if the argument I want expanded is a directory.

Comment: If tab completion isn't working for some reason, you can use the `:p` modifier to print the expanded history expression rather than executing the command when you hit enter: `mv bar_file.txt !!:2:p`.

Answer (score 2):

I am using zsh in cygwin:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 4.3.12 (i686-pc-cygwin)

$ setopt
interactive
monitor
shinstdin
zle
```

I just tried the following:

```
$ touch foo_file.txt bar_file.txt
$ mkdir -p ~/to/some/long/path/that/i/do/not/want/to/retype
$ mv foo_file.txt ~/to/some/long/path/that/i/do/not/want/to/retype
```

I then tried the tab completion mentioned above:

```
$ mv bar_file.txt !!:2[TAB]
```

and it worked fine, the last argument being expanded as follows:

```
$ mv bar_file.txt ~/to/some/long/path/that/i/do/not/want/to/retype
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pseudo-hack it in bash:

```
$ shopt -s histreedit
$ shopt -s histverify
```

Then, to actually try an expansion:

```
$ echo !!:2 [now hit enter]
$ echo histverify
```

Now you can't do tab expansion in bash.  Unequivocally no.  That's because of the order in which bash expansion is processed.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me with `zsh 4.3.17`.  Sounds like you *probably* have a bug which might be worth reporting on the [zsh-user mailing list](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/mlist.html).  However there are at least five other keybindings which should accomplish what you want: `C-x *` which is by default bound to `expand-word`, and `Esc Space` or `Meta`-`Space` or `Esc !` or `Meta`-`!` which are all bound to `expand-history` by default.  (`Meta` means the `Alt` key for many people, although it depends on your terminal setup.)

Having said that, `Esc .` (or `Meta`-`.` or `Alt-.`) is a nicer way of retrieving the last word from the previous line in the history, since it provides instant visual feedback.  You can also choose the last word from older lines by repeatedly pressing the keyboard shortcut, or even the *n* th last word on a previous line by prefixing the shortcut with `Alt`-*n* (or `Meta`-*n* or `Esc` *n*).  So for example to retrieve the penultimate word from the 3rd newest line of history, the sequence would be:

- `Meta`-`.` (goes back one line of history, selecting the last word from that line)
- `Meta`-`.` (goes back another, again selecting the last word)
- `Meta`-`2` `Meta`-`.` (goes back another, but this time selects the penultimate word from that line)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried what you've described, and I don't think bash supports this either.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, Alt-. is typically bound to yank-last-arg, which will give you what you want.

Here is a link to the whole list of history related commands that can be bound to keystrokes
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History

For example,

```
ls /etc/passwd /etc/group
cat 
# press Alt+. (Alt dot) here, bash adds /etc/group
cat /etc/group
# press space, then press Alt+1 Alt+.
# bash adds the first argument of the previous command /etc/passwd
cat /etc/group /etc/passwd
```